# Is there any way to use hg copy from a specific revision?

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way to use hg copy from a specific revision?

I want to copy an earlier version of a file and work on it while preserving the history of the copied file at the point it was copied.

In other words if I have some program `foo.py` at rev 23 but I want to fork it into `bar.py` from rev 6 of `foo.py`, is there a way to specify:

```
hg copy foo.py@6 bar.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single command that would do this because you have to add a commit as a child of the older revision. But it can certainly be done in a series of commands.

Example:

```
hg up 6
hg copy foo.py bar.py
hg commit -m "Copied foo to bar because reasons"
hg up tip
hg merge
```

This will create file `bar.py` which would be the contents of `foo.py` at revision 6.

(For private/unpublished changes you could also use `rebase` and/or `histedit` but that seems out of scope for this question).

`bar.py` may receive merges intended for `foo.py` which can be undesirable, especially if a lot of changes have occurred since rev 6. You may just have to discard conflicts.

---

If it is acceptable to have the copied file's lifetime start from the current revision its simpler:

Example:

```
hg cat --rev=6 --output bar.py foo.py
hg copy -A foo.py bar.py
hg commit -m "Create bar.py from earlier revision of foo.py"
```

*In many cases this would be OK* - for instance if there were no content changes to foo.py in all that time, but maybe only its location or filename changed.

---

FYI the reason `hg copy` by itself can't be used for this is its basic definition:

> mark files as copied for the next commit

(according to `hg cp --help`) so that is not what you should use; its just not designed for what you had in mind.